# How I can place a timestamp into my deployed filename upon deployment?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Once I deploy my app I want to do:

[image]

In order words I want the deployed zip file to be appended (or prepended) with a timestamp. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The anser is easy. In the S3 Object key place:

```
^prefix^_php_{datetime}.zip
```

Where `^prefix^` is the censored part on the screeshot you provided. The `{datetime}` part of the object name is replaced with a datetime.